# SQL Server to Oracle SQL Developer Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this script written in SQL Server 2008 and need to convert it to Oracle SQL this way I can run it in Oracle SQL Developer.  Would anyone know the correct syntax?  The main things here I would like to know are the following: 1) Declaring local variables 2) Setting local variables 3) Use the local variables 4) Using dates.  Thanks very much for your help in advanced.

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(55)
DECLARE @Age INT
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SET @NAME = 'Tim'
SET @Age = 55
SET @StartDate = '5/10/1999'
SET @EndDate = '9/22/2008'

SELECT *
FROM TblIdentifier ident
WHERE Name = @Name AND 
      Age = @Age AND 
      Birthday BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
ORDER BY ident.ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You should consider looking at SQL Plus instead for the scripting.  Follow the link in the comment above.   There is a way to kind of fake what you want, so you can use it in SQL Developer.  Here is a simple example

```
WITH
konstants AS
(
    SELECT 'Tim' NAME,
           55    AGE
    FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
FROM TblIdentifier 
WHERE NAME = (SELECT NAME FROM konstants) 
  AND AGE  = (SELECT AGE  FROM konstants)
```

This puts the constants at the top of the query, so they are in only one place, and it is easy to find and change when you need to.

Comment: Would dates work the same way?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.   It is a little trickier.  '10/10/2013' is a string not a date.  You would need to use the built in TO_DATE function to turn the string into a date.

Comment: Would you be able to add that to your example so I have a better idea?  Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: It is left as an exercise for the reader.